# Kendo grid with knockout - access variable contents from template

Tags: templates, knockout.js, grid, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid and I declare this column for it:

```
                {
                    width: 30,
                    sortable: true,
                    title: 'Title',
                    field: "status",
                    template: "#if(data.status=='false'){#= window.oooo #}else{#<span />#}#"
                },
```

As you may probably guess, I want to access a variable (that is not on the row-model), say global variable `window.oooo` in order to display it in the cell.

But this doesn't work (it displays the code as is).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to properly close off the initial `if` statement before inserting your `window.oooo` like:

```
template: "#if(data.status=='false'){# #=window.oooo # #}else{#<span />#}#"
```

Live sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Z6rjw/

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great! And I thought I was beggining to grasp this # sysntax... I have more things to learn... :)

Comment: With the # syntax you just need to wrap all of your JavaScript in it and then use #=# for outputting model properties. You can also use ternary expressions when outputting model properties e.g. #= value1 !== null ? value1 : value2# which is nice; so you could write your template as:'#=data.status === "false" ? window.oooo : "<span/>" #' :)